# Marklogic - Trouble with mem-node-replace

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am using **mem:node-replace** for replacing the content.But it is taking too much of time.I got a **time-out** error.
Is there any alternative for this?

Find the Sample Xquery:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace html = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
import module namespace mem = "http://xqdev.com/in-mem-update" 
  at '/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/in-mem-update.xqy';


let $uri := cts:uri-match((concat('*',$id ,'*')),(),cts:collection-query($collection))
let $data := doc($uri)
let $final := mem:node-replace($data//title[@id='2'],doc($uri1)//title[@id='2'])
return (
  xdmp:document-insert('/test/sample.xml',$final)
)
```

Comment: Your code snippet does not show where $id comes from. Could it be empty, causing you to be applying node-replace on the entire collection $collection?

Comment: I have pass all the parameters , This is the main code snippet only .

Answer (score 5):

`mem:node-replace()` is not the most efficient way to modify content.

If your documents are already in the database, and you simply want to replace a node, then there is no need to use the in-mem-update library.

**You should use [`xdmp:node-replace()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-replace).**

For more complex transformations you might also consider the following options for in-memory transforms:

- Ryan Dew has a similar library https://github.com/ryanjdew/XQuery-XML-Memory-Operations that performs much better. It has functions that provide a similar style of coding to the in-mem-update library.
- XSLT performs extremely well. You can use `xdmp:xslt-eval()` with a local XSLT variable, or `xdmp:xslt-invoke()` with an XSLT that has been loaded into the Modules database. It is a little different programming style, but can often outperform and be developed more simply using a modified [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) as a "push style" stylesheet with specific templates for the changes you need to make.
- A [recursive typeswitch](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/typeswitch)

**If you need to modify an extremely large number of documents, then you still may start to run into timeout issues if you attempt to do it all in a single module execution.**

You should look to manage bulk document changes with batch tools, such as:

- [MarkLogic Java Client - DMSDK](https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/data-movement-sdk)
- [Spring Batch](https://github.com/marklogic-community/marklogic-spring-batch)
- [CoRB2](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2)